# Kubernetes PVC expansion not working. Error: PVC: "didn't find a plugin capable of expanding the volume"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

I am getting the following error while expanding PVC(`kubectl edit pvc csi-expand-pvc`) and I have no idea why,

```
Event occurred" object="default/csi-expand-pvc" kind="PersistentVolumeClaim" apiVersion="v1" type="Warning" reason="ExternalExpanding" message="Ignoring the PVC: didn't find a plugin capable of expanding the volume; waiting for an external controller to process this PVC.
```

Here is the spec for my PVC.

```
apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    name: csi-expand-pvc
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 100Gi
    storageClassName: ab-storage



#kubectl  get pvc
    
  NAME               STATUS   VOLUME         CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS       AGE
  csi-expand-pvc     Bound    pvc-675765658   100Gi      RWO            ab-storage        33m
```

feature-gates ExpandInUsePersistentVolumes,ExpandCSIVolumes are enabled.
allowVolumeExpansion is also set to true under storage class.

```
setup details

 kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"**v1.23.5**", GitCommit:"c285e781331a3785a7f436042c65c5641ce8a9e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-03-16T15:57:37Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
 quay.io/k8scsi/csi-provisioner:v2.1.2
 quay.io/k8scsi/csi-attacher:v3.1.0 
 quay.io/k8scsi/csi-snapshotter:v4.0.0 
 quay.io/k8scsi/csi-resizer:v1.1.0
```

Comment: Is this a self-managed k8s or managed cluster like GKE, EKS etc?

Answer (score 0):

As per above error it says that exisiting storage provisioner is not capable of expending the pvc.

Check the storage provisioner details from the  description of the storage class your pvc is using.

Then check whether the current provisioner has the capability to extend the volume.